# There is a faulty gravatar in this chat room

Tags: bug, chat-ads

I know this has a duplicate somewhere, but I can't find it. A Gravatar that seems to belong to Jeremy Banks is breaking the Chat ad:

[image]

Weirdly, if I click on the Gravatar, I'm taken to [Jeremy's profile](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134300) which shows a different Gravatar. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: ...although that's not the same gravatar that I see, not sure how that happened.

Comment: again? what did i miss?

Comment: And here I thought this was going to be a hilarious, vitriolic "all hi-rep users abuse newbies" rant. Disappointing, Pekka.

Comment: @Popular I know, this was blatant false advertising. I couldn't resist the opportunity

Comment: The man needs his space, cut him some slack.